# How do I find out the time zone name from ISO 8601 string in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I have time in ISO 8601 format.

```
2014-08-19T23:26:23+09:00
```

How do I find out the time zone name from the time string.

I tried below.

```
Time.zone.parse('2014-08-19T23:26:23+09:00')
# This returns the time in the time zone I have set(UTC by default)

Time.parse('2014-08-19T23:26:23+09:00')
# This returns the time in the system time zone
```

If I know the time zone name I can do

```
Time.parse('2014-08-19T23:26:23+09:00').in_time_zone('Asia/Tokyo').zone.name
=> 'JST'
```

Unfortunately I don't have the time zone name. Any idea?

Comment: The time string could refer to any time zone with an UTC offset of +09:00, not just Asia/Tokyo

Comment: Read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to do that. There is no mapping from offset to time zone (although there is a mapping from time zone to offset for a fixed time of year). Many time zones may share a single offset.